# Does Django support integer enums for model fields similar to models.TextChoices?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, enums

I'm using Django 3.2 and Python 3.9 and Postgres.  I have the below model in which I want to constrain one of the fields ("type") to be from a predefined enum ...

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    class TransactionTypes(models.TextChoices):
        BUY = 'BUY', _('Buy')
        SELL = 'SELL', _('Sell')
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=datetime.now)
    price = models.FloatField(null=False)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=False)
    type = models.CharField(
        null=False,
        max_length=5,
        choices=TransactionTypes.choices,
    )

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['created']),
```

However, this is slightly space-inefficient as I'm using a character type when I feel I shoudl be using an integer type for the enums.  Does Django have anything out of the box that can accommodate integer enum types?

Comment: Yes, there is `models.IntegerChoices` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use `choices` with `IntegerField`. You can use `PositiveSmallIntegerField` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield) to be even more space-conscious. Here's an example with your code:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    class TransactionTypes(models.TextChoices):
        BUY = 1, _('Buy')
        SELL = 0, _('Sell')
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(null=False, default=datetime.now)
    price = models.FloatField(null=False)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=False)
    type = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        null=False,
        choices=TransactionTypes.choices,
    )

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['created']),
```